# Mac OS Snow Leopard: Why does my mysql.default_socket value not change in my phpinfo() page?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2, osx-snow-leopard

I'm getting errors whenever I try to connect locally to mySQL on Mac OS Snow Leopard 10.6.4. I'm running mySQL 5.1.46. I can log in using the console. I'm running PHP 5.3.2 and my `phpinfo()` page is working fine. So I've got PHP running, I can log into the mySQL server using both the console and Sequel Pro.

So I suspected that it was a socket issue. In my /etc directory, I don't have php.ini, I have php.ini.default. So I go in there, and every place I see "default_socket" I change it from:

```
/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

to:

```
/tmp/mysql.sock
```

I see it in the following locations:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

And when I go to connect to phpMyAdmin, I get the following error:
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.

And when I look in my `phpinfo()` file, I get the following under mySQL:

```
mysql.default_socket /var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I restart Apache... heck, I restart the whole computer. Still, nothing. I know mySQL is working, I know PHP is working, but I can't get them talking.

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

PHP should be looking for a php.ini file (and not php.ini.default) to load, so try renaming php.ini.default to php.ini. See [Install Apache/PHP/MySQL on Snow Leopard](http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard).

Comment: This was the one that fixed it. Then I read Vikash's answer to see why. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to muck about with config settings for either mysql or php, then set up this hack:

> **mkdir /var/mysql**
>
> **ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock**

This creates an alias in the location that PHP is looking for that connects to the real mysql.sock.

Comment: Awesome. Works and you don't even have to restart anything!

Answer (score 1):

> Bring the mysql.sock to PHP
>
> One problem that has come about with
>   MySQL and Leopard is the location of
>   the mysql.sock file. Previously, the
>   default location for this file was in
>   the /tmp directory. That location has
>   now moved to the /var/mysql directory.
>   PHP will look for it there.
>   Unfortunately, the default location
>   from the MySQL will still place it in
>   the old location. We can fix this by
>   creating a my.cnf configuration file
>   in the /etc directory. Save a file
>   with the following contents to
>   /etc/my.cnf:
>
> [client] socket =
>   /var/mysql/mysql.sock
>
> [mysqld] socket =
>   /var/mysql/mysql.sock
>
> In the terminal window, type the
>   following commands to create the
>   directory for the sock file:
>
> sudo mkdir /var/mysql sudo chown
>   _mysql /var/mysql

Source: http://www.procata.com/blog/archives/2007/10/28/working-with-php-5-in-mac-os-x-105/

Comment: Thank you so much for the awesome answer. Renaming the php.ini.default file worked, but I understand it much better thanks to this response.

Answer (score 1):

Simply creating the /etc/my.cnf file with contents and creating the directory, per Vikash's recommendation, did not solve the problem. mysql.sock still was living in /tmp, even after doing this and restarting the machine. I manually moved the file from /tmp to /var/mysql, and then the error resolved. I had a feeling, though, that upon restart the problem would resurface, and it did. This time the error was slightly different - connection denied. I found that a new socket had been opened in /tmp and the old one was still there in /var/mysql; the code was trying to use the old one and getting denied access. So I used Sid's hack with the symlink and that fixed the problem. I'm sure when I restart, this fix will still work. However, I'd love to know what is causing the system to open new sockets in /tmp instead of the configured /var/mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to resolve the issue (Mac OS x) -

1.) First go to your apache webroot (**path available from /etc/apache2/httpd.conf  -> DocumentRoot**). For me it was /Library/WebServer/Documents/

1.1) Create a showphpconfig.php at that location

2.) Go and visit this file in your browser : http://127.0.0.1/showphpconfig.php

This will show you what configuration file your apache server is using

For me it was using `/private/etc/php.ini`

I also saw that php was using the mysql sock file from `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

3.) I made a copy of the php.ini file. Open it and find all the lines which have mysql.sock.

copy those lines and create a new entry, like below -

`;pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock`

**IMP** the ";" in front of the first line, that is commenting out the first line
There should be about 4 such lines

Now you have told php, that the mysql socket file is actually present in the /tmp folder

4.) restart your apache server - `apachectl restart`

And you should see the wordpress configuration screen

Answer (score 1):

Try just doing a symlink.
For my XAMPP installation this worked:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ /var/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be a problem related to sockets. Try connecting to MySQL from a simple PHP script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
echo 'No errors';
?>
```

For your PHP.ini path, look in `phpinfo();` for "Loaded Configuration File". It does not have to be located in `/etc/php.ini.default`

Comment: Lekensteyn, I created a page named "test.php" and pasted your code with the appropriate un/pw and got this error:


Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php on line 3
No such file or directory